# mysql and oracle issue using dblink

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle11g, dblink

My issue is between mysql and oracle communication:

**Step 1 (Creating a view in mysql for corresponding table)**

E.g:

```
  CREATE VIEW piwik_log_link_view ( idvis, cusk )
  AS SELECT CAST( CONV( HEX( idvisitor ), 16, 10 ) AS CHAR(1000) )
          , custom_var_k1
     FROM   piwik_log_link_visit_action
```

**Step 2: (Firing a query from Oracle through dblink)**

E.g:

```
SELECT plv."idvis"
     , plv."cusk" 
FROM   "piwik_log_link_view"@mysql_piwik plv
```

**Result**:

Showing error: `ORA-00904: "PLV"."cusk": invalid identifier.`

If change step 2 to fetch only one column

I.E.

```
SELECT plv."idvis"
FROM "piwik_log_link_view"@mysql_piwik plv
```

**Result :**

Showing the first column.. .

Incase of putting `*` also in select query shows only one column.

Comment: What is the data type of `custom_var_k1`?

Comment: I have exactly same problem, and I noticed that when, on MySQL, varchar is longer a number value between 2000 and 4000, the column disappears on Oracle and its DBLink.